# Solve $xu_x+yu_y+zu_z=4u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

\begin{cases}
xu_x+yu_y+zu_z=4u\\
u(x,y,1)=xy\\
\end{cases}

Using Lagrange method we get:

$$\frac{x}{y}=c_1, \frac{y}{z}=c_2, \frac{z}{\sqrt[4]{u}}=c_3$$

So the general solution is $$u=\frac{z^4}{c_3}$$?

Comment: Any homogeneous function of degree four satisfies that PDE, so how about $xyz^2$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown a second thought is $F(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z})=\frac{z^4}{u}$ and to use $u(x,y,1)=xy$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to spherical coordinates, we get

$$ru_r = 4u \implies u = f(\theta,\phi)r^4$$

Then plugging in our boundary condition at $r\cos\theta = 1$ and $xy=r^2\sin^2\theta\sin\phi\cos\phi$, we can get

$$f(\theta,\phi)r^4 = r^2\sin^2\theta\sin\phi\cos\phi\cdot(1)=r^2\sin^2\theta\sin\phi\cos\phi\cdot (r^2\cos^2\theta)$$

$$\implies f(\theta,\phi) = \cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta\sin\phi\cos\phi$$

by canceling out the $r^4$ on both sides. In other words when we convert back to Cartesian we get the solution

$$u(x,y,z) = xyz^2$$